# Non-leaf node in B+ tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Assume a B+ tree with order m. Why is it that the non-leaf node must have at least ceil(m / 2) childs? Or what will happen if this property is not satisfied.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework-like question with no evidence of prior work by the asker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't enforce the half-full rule, you can get (effectively) unbalanced tree, e.g.

```
                      [root]
                     /      \_________________________
                    /                                 \
            [branch]                                   [branch]
           /        \                             ____/    |   \___
          /          \                           /         |       \
[1-record leaf] [1-record leaf] [100-record leaf] [100-record leaf] [100-record leaf]
```

It's going to take much less time to find the first or second record in this tree than to find any of the other 300 records.

If you let leaves have as few as one record and branches have as few as one key (and therefore two children), I believe the disparity in lookup time can be as bad as log(m) (where m is the order of the tree). Looking up a record along a path of full nodes takes Θ(log(N) * log(m)) time (where N = total number of records, so log(N) is proportional to the height of the tree), while looking up a record along a path of minimally-sized nodes only takes Θ(log(N)) time (because you do exactly one comparison at each branch and none at the leaf).

By enforcing the half-full rule, you ensure that all lookup times are Θ(log(N) * log(m)) and within a constant factor of each other.